# Run 10 Loops at a time

Tags: python

Okay, so I can do this in PowerShell as that is my specialty, however, I having issues trying to accomplish this in Python.

See my [PowerShell example here](https://github.com/greyboxsoftware/PowerShell-Registry-Search-MultiThread/blob/master/multiThreadSearch.ps1) on what I am trying to do.

Essentially this is what I am trying to do in pseudo-code:

```
objArray = [
    {"name": "Test User", "address": "123 Movie Road"}, 
    {"name": "Test User", "address": "444 Music Road"}
]

#I want to run the below loop 10 at a time

for obj in objArray: 
     print(obj["name"])
```

Obviously, this is oversimplified however, I hope this outlines what I need to do.

Comment: Are you trying to do [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)?

Comment: Don't know powershell, but by looking at your code, it looks like you're looking for a way to asynchronously execute a block of code, for each object in your array?

Comment: If you want to run the loops in parallel/concurrent you can write a function for it and start this function in 10 [threads](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html)

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clearer what you are trying to do. So far four people have thought it might mean four different things. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @UliSotschok this is what I’m trying to do however I don’t know what that code looks like and I tried Thread examples however it didn’t work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range` with a step value.

```
step = 10
for batch_idx in range(0, len(objArray), step):
    for obj in objArray[batch_idx:(batch_idx + step)]:
        print(obj['name'])
```

You can extend this using, for example, multithreading:

```
from threading import Thread

def foo(objects):
    for obj in objects:
        print(obj['name'])

step = 10
for batch_idx in range(0, len(objArray), step):
    objects = objArray[batch_idx:(batch_idx + step)]
    t = Thread(target=foo, args=(objects,))
    t.start()
```

Comment: What does this do differently to the code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

To execute something in parallel/concurrent you need threads. Luckily Python has an easy to use API for this. You need to import the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html) library.

To run an thread you need to create a new Thread object and start it. The Thread object needs at least a `target` argument, which tells him which function to run.

e.g.

```
import threading

def do_something():
    for i in range(10):
        print("Executed in thread")

thread = threading.Thread(target=do_something)

thread.start()
```

Note that the target must be an executable function. This means only enter pass the name without parenthesis.

To run 10 threads you need to create 10 threads and start them. 
Your final code could something like this:

```
import threading

objArray = [
    {"name": "Test User", "address": "123 Movie Road"}, 
    {"name": "Test User", "address": "444 Music Road"}
]


def my_loop():
    for obj in objArray: 
        print(obj["name"])

for i in range(10): 
    thread = threading.Thread(target=my_loop)
    thread.start()
```